# Android 12 (API 31) - Fragment not being destroyed when going in background

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-lifecycle

I'm having this issue with my fragment only in API 31. In the host `Activity` I use `replace` to add my fragment:

```
transaction.replace(container, fragment, tag);
```

Everything runs as expected. But when I send the app in background in API 31 the fragment's lifecycle doesn't evolve as I was thinking. It doesn't call `onDestroy`. It only goes till `onStop`. Meanwhile, in previous versions of Android the fragment gets completely destroyed when I send the app to background.

Anyone else experiencing this problem?

Comment: As per official document they are suggesting to use Navigation Component instead of fragment transactions.
Try Implementing that.

Comment: @SiddarthJain We are having this app developed since 2015 in our corporate. Migrating to NavComponents is not going to happen any soon.

Comment: @SiddarthJain - whats "recommended" has got nothing to do with possible behavioural changes in API31?  Also navigation component will ultimately just be abstractions over fragment transactions ..